# JdbcTemplate.queryForObject unable to bind arguments to query

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc

I'm using JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper rowMapper, Object... args) to get one row from Oracle but keep getting EmptyResultDataAccessException Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0.

I have verified my SQL using Oracle SQL Developer and it returns 1 row just like it should.

1. This keeps failing.

   ```
   public NgsRecord getUserInfoByImsi(String imsi) throws SQLException {
     String sql = "SELECT snb, timestamp_, user_type, real_exch, act_exch, dev_type, rc FROM port WHERE imsi = ?";

     RowMapper<NgsRecord> mapper = new RowMapper<NgsRecord>() {
         public NgsRecord mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
               throws SQLException {
             NgsRecord ngsRecord = new NgsRecord();
             ngsRecord.setTimestamp(rs.getDate("timestamp_"));
             ngsRecord.setUser_type(rs.getString("user_type"));
             ngsRecord.setReal_exch(rs.getString("real_exch"));
             ngsRecord.setAct_exch(rs.getString("act_exch"));
             ngsRecord.setDev_type(rs.getString("dev_type"));
             ngsRecord.setRc(rs.getString("rc"));
             ngsRecord.setSnb(rs.getString("snb"));
             return ngsRecord;
         }
     };
     return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, mapper, imsi);
   }
   ```
2. This works.

   ```
   public NgsRecord getUserInfoByImsi(String imsi) throws SQLException {
     String sql = "SELECT snb, timestamp_, user_type, real_exch, act_exch, dev_type, rc FROM port WHERE imsi = '" + imsi + "'";

     RowMapper<NgsRecord> mapper = new RowMapper<NgsRecord>() {
         public NgsRecord mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                 throws SQLException {
             NgsRecord ngsRecord = new NgsRecord();
             ngsRecord.setTimestamp(rs.getDate("timestamp_"));
             ngsRecord.setUser_type(rs.getString("user_type"));
             ngsRecord.setReal_exch(rs.getString("real_exch"));
             ngsRecord.setAct_exch(rs.getString("act_exch"));
             ngsRecord.setDev_type(rs.getString("dev_type"));
             ngsRecord.setRc(rs.getString("rc"));
             ngsRecord.setSnb(rs.getString("snb"));
             return ngsRecord;
         }
     };
     return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, mapper);
   }
   ```
3. This works.

   ```
   public NgsRecord getUserInfo(String snb) throws SQLException {
     String sql = "SELECT snb, timestamp_, user_type, real_exch, act_exch, dev_type, rc FROM port WHERE snb = ?";

     RowMapper<NgsRecord> mapper = new RowMapper<NgsRecord>() {
         public NgsRecord mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
               throws SQLException {
             NgsRecord ngsRecord = new NgsRecord();
             ngsRecord.setTimestamp(rs.getDate("timestamp_"));
             ngsRecord.setUser_type(rs.getString("user_type"));
             ngsRecord.setReal_exch(rs.getString("real_exch"));
             ngsRecord.setAct_exch(rs.getString("act_exch"));
             ngsRecord.setDev_type(rs.getString("dev_type"));
             ngsRecord.setRc(rs.getString("rc"));
             ngsRecord.setSnb(rs.getString("snb"));
             return ngsRecord;
         }
     };
     return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, mapper, snb);
   }
   ```
4. Sample 1 updated and works.

   ```
   public NgsRecord getUserInfoByImsi(String imsi) throws SQLException {
     SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("imsi", imsi);
     String sql = "/*+ INDEX(NGS.PORT IDX_PORT_IMSI) */ SELECT snb, timestamp_, user_type, real_exch, act_exch, dev_type, rc FROM port WHERE imsi = RPAD(:imsi, 16, ' ')";
     return (NgsRecord) namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, namedParameters, new NgsRecordRowMapper());
   }
   ```

The only difference in code sample 1 and 3 are the Oracle data types for imsi and snb. Imsi is CHAR(16 BYTE) and snb is VARCHAR2(18 BYTE).

Is there a difference in how I should bind the arguments to the query for these two types?

> Yes, there is difference!

Since CHAR(16 BYTE) is fixed length and my Java String input contains only 15 characters I have to instruct Oracle to pad my input with spaces till it's exactly 16 characters. That's where **RPAD(:imsi, 16, ' ')** comes in.

I based my solution on [8.3.1  CHAR, VARCHAR, and LONGVARCHAR](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html) and [Use a CHAR field in the WHERE clause in a PreparedStatement](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-oracle-char-field-preparedstatement.html)

Comment: Instead of passing imsi, have you tried passing SqlParameterValue(Types.CHAR, imsi)?  The javadoc for queryForObject says that it leaves "it to the PreparedStatement to guess the corresponding SQL type" unless you provide a "SqlParameterValue objects which indicate not only the argument value but also the SQL type and optionally the scale."

Comment: I tried this as well `return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {new SqlParameterValue(OracleTypes.CHAR, imsi)}, mapper);`

Comment: @MarkLeiber see my updated post with solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

which spring version are you using because I cannot find method in `jdbcTemplate` which matches 
`ueryForObject(String sql,  RowMapper rowMapper,Object[] args)`
you can refer [URL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)

I can only find below three overloaded methods which takes rowMapper

```
queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, RowMapper rowMapper) ;
queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper rowMapper) ;
queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper rowMapper) ;
```

looking at your problem I would suggest you using 
`queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, RowMapper rowMapper)` method where you should pass the parameter type.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: I can see that  its mentioned , I really don't know why its not mentioned in the URL I have mentioned ?

Comment: This is the link to the docs [Class JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: Yes I can see that this method is added now. Could you please try to use `queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, RowMapper rowMapper) '  by specifying the specific type ? as you mentioned there is only type difference in both sql's. I think its worth to give a try.

Comment: I tried this `return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {new SqlParameterValue(OracleTypes.CHAR, imsi)}, mapper);` but it didn't work

Comment: @Shirish I tried your suggestion but it didn't work `return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {imsi}, new int[] {Types.CHAR}, mapper);`